# What font is this

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

Just a simple question: what font is this and where can I find it for free?[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. We have special [requirements for font ID questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/89608). Could you please review these and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/158124/edit) accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second attempt to identify this typeface, using https://www.whatfontis.com/ resulted in a perfect match.

[image: Gabriola ttf (400) typeface]

Image from linked site using first word as search key in linked site.

It is not listed as a free font on this site and my search attempts ceased after positive identification. The remainder of the question is left as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's Gabriola-not a free font, but installed on Windows computers and Macs with Microsoft Office, so you may have it already.

To get the most out of it, it's [definitely worth reading this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100824155722/http://gabriolan.ca/gabriola-font-variants/) on its alternate characters. That 'a' in particular strikes me as quite mannered, I would recommend replacing it with the single-story 'a' on stylistic sets 1, 3, 5 and 7. You can use different stylistic sets for each individual letter to customize it better into exactly the form you want.